# Android - Broadcast receiver to detect headset button click not working on API 23 (marshmallow)

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm using a broadcast receiver to detect headset button click. Below is the code for broadcast receiver.

```
public class HeadSetButtonStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON)) {
            KeyEvent event = (KeyEvent) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
            if (event != null) {
                int action = event.getAction();
                if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "BUTTON PRESSED!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    EventBus.getDefault().post(new HeadSetButtonEvent("1"));
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

It works fine on API 22 (lollipop) but it does not work on API 23 (marshmallow devices). I tried to look on stackoverflow but did not find anything.

Comment: What is your target API @Vicky?

Comment: @CrazyAndroid API 23.

Comment: @CrazyAndroid No but I'm registering the broadcast receiver in the activity not in the manifest file.

Comment: check this post https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/index.html

Comment: @CrazyAndroid Please try to be specific, that article is huge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try int instead

```
if (Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(intent.getAction())) {
    KeyEvent event = (KeyEvent)intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
    int intKey = event.getKeyCode();
}
```

You probably get 2 different int values for 1 button.

Answer (score 0):

```
 check the priority

 IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON); 
    MediaButtonIntentReceiver recev = new MediaButtonIntentReceiver();
    filter.setPriority(1000);  
    registerReceiver(recev , filter);
```

Comment: Still not working after setting `filter.setPriority(1000);`.